# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in SessionsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the above error when logging out of my Rails app.  I see others have had the same error when using Devise, but I'm not using that gem. Here is my SessionsController.rb:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create 
    chef = Chef.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if chef && chef.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:chef_id] = chef.id
      cookies.signed[:chef_id] = chef.id
      flash[:success] = "You have successfully logged in."
      redirect_to chef
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "There was something wrong with your login information."
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:chef_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "You have logged out."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Much thanks for any help.

Here is my log out button,which is part of my navigation bar:

```
<li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
      <% end %>
```

Here is a larger portion of my _navigation partial with the logout button:

> 

```
<% if logged_in? %><%#Changes drop-down menu options if logged in.%>
>           <li class="dropdown">
>             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%=
> current_chef.chefname.titleize %>'s Profile <%= "Admin" if
> current_chef.admin? %><span class="caret"></span></a>
>             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>               <li><%= link_to "View your profile", chef_path(current_chef) %></li>
>               <li><%= link_to "Edit your profile", edit_chef_path(current_chef) %></li>
>               <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
>               <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
>               <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete%></li>
>             </ul>
>           </li>
>           <% else %>
>             <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
>           <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you provide view piece, that contains your 'Logout' button?

Comment: @AntonTkachov Thanks for your reply.  I've aded my logout button code above.

Comment: Can you also paste your layout?

Comment: Do you use jquery_ujs in your application?

Comment: @AntonTkachov - I'm only using the jquery-rails gem.  There are several files in my layout: _footer, _messages, _navigation, application,   Anything in particular?

Comment: Add my responses. Add csrf_meta_tag to your head section. It should work with jquery-rails too

Comment: @AntonTkachov Ok, I'll look at that.  Thanks again.  I tried to up vote your answer but I don't have enough rep points for it to register.  Strange policy.

Comment: But you still can mark my question as a `solution` with a check mark if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are missing `csrf_meta_tag` statement in your layout (keep in mind that it requires jquery_ujs/jquery-rails to work properly). Try to add it and check whether it works

Answer (score 0):

`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error is not related to Devise gem, check [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) for `protect_from_forgery`. Look inside your application controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll look at that.  I tried to up vote your answer but I don't have enough rep points for it to register.  Strange policy.